# tFPDF creates non-valid PDF

Tags: php, cakephp, fpdf

I already checked some existing answers, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51794930/tfpdf-generates-an-empty-pdf-file). But they don't solve my problem.
I'm migrating from `FPDF` to `tFPDF` (here the http://fpdf.org/fr/script/script92.php).

I used this test code, pretty the same of the official "Hello world":

```
require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'tfpdf' . DS . 'tfpdf.php');
$this->response = $this->response->withType('pdf');
$this->response = $this->response->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="some.pdf"');
$this->layout = 'document';

$pdf = new tFPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',14);
$pdf->Write(8,"Blabla");

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
$pdf->Ln(10);
$pdf->Write(5,"La taille de ce PDF n'est que de 13 ko.");

$this->set('fpdf', $pdf);
$this->render('document');
```

}

Layout `document`:

```
<?php
    echo $content;
```

View `document`:

```
<?php
    $this->set('content', $fpdf->Output('S'));
```

Using `FPDF` all works fine: I can view the generated PDF document.
With `tFPDF` the document is unreadable. It doesn't work even leaving only the `AddPage` method.

Is there something other I have to do that is not documented?

### UPDATE

Here the binary content of the file, saved with the `F` option:

```
%PDF-1.3
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/Resources 2 0 R
/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 118>>
stream
x\9C3R\F0\E22\D035W(\E7r
Q\D0w3T04\D130PISp
    \EAZ*\98[Z\80ES4\9Cr\92@\A4\A6BHT\9D\BE\9B\AD\E6\C6z\96\86`\AD>\89
%\89\9999\A9
)\A9
ɩ
.n
y\EA\A9\C5%
\85\A5`1Cc\85\EC|=\98\A9\00P$d
endstream
endobj
1 0 obj
<</Type /Pages
/Kids [3 0 R ]
/Count 1
/MediaBox [0 0 595.28 841.89]
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type /Font
/Subtype /Type0
/BaseFont /MPDFAA+DejaVuSansCondensed
/Encoding /Identity-H
/DescendantFonts [6 0 R]
/ToUnicode 7 0 R
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Type /Font
/Subtype /CIDFontType2
/BaseFont /MPDFAA+DejaVuSansCondensed
/CIDSystemInfo 8 0 R
/FontDescriptor 9 0 R
/DW 540
/W [ 32 [ 286 360 414 754 572 855 702 247 351 351 450 754 286 325 286 303 ]
 48 57 572 58 59 303 60 62 754 63 [ 478 900 615 617 628 693 568 518 697 677 265 265 590 501 776 673 708 542 708 625 571 549 659 615 890 616 549 616 351 303 351 754 450 450 551 571 495 571 554 316 571 570 250 250 521 250 876 570 550 571 571 370 469 353 570 532 736 532 532 472 572 303 572 754 ]
 ]
/CIDToGIDMap 10 0 R
>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Length 345>>
stream
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo
<</Registry (Adobe)
/Ordering (UCS)
/Supplement 0
>> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
1 beginbfrange
<0000> <FFFF> <0000>
endbfrange
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end
endstream
endobj
8 0 obj
<</Registry (Adobe)
/Ordering (UCS)
/Supplement 0
>>
endobj
9 0 obj
<</Type /FontDescriptor
/FontName /MPDFAA+DejaVuSansCondensed
 /Ascent 928
 /Descent -236
 /CapHeight 928
 /Flags 4
 /FontBBox [-918 -463 1614 1232]
 /ItalicAngle 0
 /StemV 87
 /MissingWidth 540
/FontFile2 11 0 R
>>
endobj
10 0 obj
<</Length 169
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
x\9C\ED̹
\0001\E7\DB\E5x\80t*C\96tU\A1\91ڌޫ\F6c=Q\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\BEt\F6\EC\00
endstream
endobj
11 0 obj
<</Length 6306
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length1 18824
>>
stream
x\9C\ED<x\e\95\FF\9D37)$!\AD \B4\FEM    \B40\9DԤiv\92L\D3i\F3bf\92\B6"no\E6\DE\C9L;3w\98;I\BB\E5a)H\8B\82\91\97\C8"\B6Zԭ,B\A5\B8\8B\B2\8Al\AD\A2X\CBBeQ\97Ut17{\FE\FF\DE;\8F<J_\FC\BE\CD43\FF\E3\FC\E7}\CE\E6d\A6D"\84T\92\AB   \90
]\A1\86\C6\F5\F3\9Eĕ\97\F1\B77\92T\D2\C4$_#Dj\C5ywd0\CBH|\E6E8\BF
\CDh\BA?y\C5\C2\C1\8D\84\00\CE\C9\FD\8A\91&\A5\F8 \EE8/\EFOG\CF\F0}\ECu\9C\B7#\FC\B51MQ\CBc\D2\F7   \91\9F\C6\FD\C51\\A8\90J\B6R2
\E7\E7ƒ\D9\CD3\AEs\FD\00\E7\9C\9F\99\D0#\8A\F4Ai\CE9\FDʤ\B29\ED6ܗ\E1<\8Cs\96R\92ڳ\DD\FFγ\84\|SZ7\B2cא\C2\C1 Kg\B4\F4\B2\D2?క!\CD\91`\97tq\E3\B8I\BE9\9Ae\BD\C2OH\D4UC\88\AB\AC\A4\A6\B9].\F7K$5\F6C\F2\C6=w\C3<7a\E5\DDQ\BFJV66VRk\D6Jw\96&\A5\C3\884\F6\DC\B1~$\D4\D7d9b?\BER2\8D\B8\F0\C1H3\E9#\891\C7\C7
\8F=?\F6\F8\D8}cw\88$\87\C1\858\DCD\C6\E1"\B2\8F\C0\C77\C8r\B7\B4gQ\84\B8W\EEu=H\B6\93\yB: \DD\E0\9A\8Fk\BB\C8+\E4\84\BC\9E\80=n"\AD&M\B8Jȳ\B2\8B\FCI
\93\87\C7ER\ADtQi\89\9B\B8;\DD\B9\83\EE}\EE\97\DC\C9\D4\E6A\F7\B7!5\C1}r\AF\BC/\82o\A1.\9E"\EF!\FB\A4\E7\88A\85\DF@<\E6nuW\92\E7\E0 \EC!/"\D4!\D2\D8I\EE'[\90\97ZI'W\B9\B6\B8\82\B8\F2\A4|\90܉\F7J\F7H\CF w\8FJ\DB\C8!r;\B8]\AB\C8=\D2!\94\EB\00y\95l\83\B0\EB*\D4~\93+\8A\FC?\89\B8\E2\F9;\89\81J8$Qb\BA.\C45\E4i\F5\89\E7\990_>$\AF\90\AB\90r\98\DC_\B2\AF\A4\B6tR\E1\DB%=!\BD\r+\B9\97<\84+\E0\E7\D2v\F7\F7\E7ݫ\C8NK\B0\81\ECD\DCw\F23%Qie\E7\8F-\BBkȽA\DAC~\E3\DEPڇ\B8\BF\C5%B\9A\B9\82(Q\94<\86\BFC%U(\D32i;܀\9C\F2ݙ\E4`\E9jw\9EG\A5[QjBtXD6\E2h\F92y\90̇\B21  yK\96ȯ\E2ɻ\DDϣ\CC;\A5\9B]\AF\92\83\D0J摨\FBw\A8kRK\C8!\8F\94\96\C8npI\C4ê\F6\BA\EA\EA\DE\97\AEc\DFY?{\BEgܔU\95\B2\BD\A4{o\C50\DB76ֽ\CE}\B6\BC~\AF|\CE^\A8\9F\B6\D7]?\E7\F9\A96\9F\9F\EFYӽ\8E\ED}\C3\DFjc\F5ohŵ\D0:\F2.㺿U\ECq\A2{\E5z\FCذ\97EblGՎ9KwTiK\E7s\CFuq_G]f\8E\C0\AB\F2\FD8\C6,pF\F5\EC\EA\FA\D9ճ?w\BC\FE=\D7w\DFXh\8E\94V\BE\F6\C7L\C9<<hY\E2Nɇ\F0t5\C6\91\AAg7.^\B4\F0\BC9\B9A\FD\EC\C6\D3kKJgI\F8<g\B6\B4I\9As\EB\CD7\DFj\FER\AAؾm\DBv\F3b\E9駟7\D2\D7\DF\F6\E7\CCY\AE\A7\DE\F8\E5\F57޴\DD5/\D13W\A4w=\FE\95\EE\ABen\FF\CEϐ\AF\D4\D8ax\EDLI=R\AA+\99^;\A3\A9q\F1\C5Ғ\EA9\8B*\A59u\E7-Z\B8x\99ĉ֕\94.\BADjj\9C\E1\DA\FC\D4]YuǮ]\BB\DE\F7\85-w=|\F8\85_\8F|\B4\F7\FE\F6\CB\B8\F4\E7?u5E\B7\F4\CF>4\AF\FD\8Dk\F6D\95o\DC\F7\F5\C7k\AE\BA\D1\EB\DDs\FE\F9\AF\8D\EC;\EC\F6\96Ԓ2r\D2h-\92\C7]S]\E5B\9A\E7O\9FS\DD׌l\BBvd\E4\DAm#o\\F8}ߋ/\EE\D3?\B3p\F7nWÁ\97^:\80\BF\AE\A0\AA\98\8F\99\AF\E1\E31E\FD<"\C5\\F1%|
\E3P\CBM\D5s\BE\FC\B9ϕ\D4\FE\F5e+\8F \FD\ED{\F0\BA\DB\FF\F2w\A7/\FF3y\CF4\91^\9E\F9\E6\85u^_\DB\FDz{\F9oO\FBj}ZA\FE!\A5Is&!W\BE\B6{\F4p\F9o\8B\B2\FF)q\C9e\AE\00Z\ED\F2\90;NR\EEO\90\DD.\C2y!3\F0\D1N\AEE\9B~\D3\E6\A1\C2\E4BÌ\E8"U\E4N\C9=ק\F1\FCK\DE-]\92\C3\BB\D4h\8F%2]\FA\8B=v\B7\EB]\F6\C8t\CC\D6؍\E3\F6X&\E5\AEG\EDq 9\C3\F5{{\8C\E7\DB\E32\CC\F6\B8\A2\E6\D3s\BFo\8F+\C9\C2e?\B1\C7U\A4l\F9\B9\F6\B8\9A\9C\B6\BC\95gs\F7i\C8\D0A\9D\8F%r\81t\C0\A3ǻ*\EC1\90\\E7\D8c7\8E?d\8Fer\A6\EB^{\B\CEs=i\8F\A7\91:\00{\F\96\C2E\F6\B8\A2~)\DCj\8F+IlY\D2W\91\CB\CB\EDq5\A9Y\BE\80\B4`nI\93a\92!qҏ΢\E7\92fF\C9|4\E1\A8!\F8\8D\C7}3D\C3\DB'I<\B8 )\84\F7\E2\C8G\F8`$\98\C3e\88\99\86\AF\9E\C4g!\E9QP]\9C\A3FJ\83H\8Bg\C1B[7_\EC)\B6\E2h#\9E\EB\C5\FB\8E!\A5\8E96M\9CP\84DX\8F\E0C\CE\F8=\8B\B3\CET\A4\9BD\BEG   i\D1\D3Ùx,\CB\E6F\E6\B1\C6\9AX\DF0k\8Eg\8DlFS\92HE\BC̗H\B0 \872XP3\B4̠\A6z鄣\8B\F9Ѱ2\98ܨ\A7\FAY\B3\9B\E2`\AB\B6Q\E9\C0d\A9\A4\FA5\83)\8D\C5S,=З\88G\98\AA'\95x\8A\92q"\86\84\80\\B8\A18wSB-*\82ZCJ\CA`-zJ\D5R\86\86\CB\CD\A9\93M8\D0\F5M'\E1\89c\E8v4P\FB\BA\B0M#Z\B3\89,\C1
-c\C4\F5k\F46-)&䐙\92\A71%\93Qq\CAr\A4\AC\ED\E6sQ=\85vɢ\99\89p\B6,\BA\CARҀ\D5\C61\888\BCxV\C7\D7\BA\8F&\F0e\84\A3y\AF\86gH,\9BM/mhP\E9\E0\80\D7\D02-\AAg\FA5oJ\C3\ED\958\8E\E9\C7\C4\E4{\:M\8C\86n\AB\93!\84\E5\E1qr\9C\9EcjÝa\84\89\89\93q\DCK\B9\B2B\AF\kq\82\87$\C7:8N\93\E3\E5\C8\F5@QPO%
\C5\C7d\B2[\EE\A1\E0\A8Pk\D3%\F3O\E0A\8F*e\9D\FCD9\B9\BD\F32\C7q\87\8AQV\ACp/L
]o\C25-\F0f\BCpɺ\BE\A4\C0\96\B4\B8\E0)&\F64[\AE~A%e[\DDc\DBݲ\96E\CD\F21\CB\DF=\82/]X?%Χ\ED`\B6(\E8\885k\FBX\DC\F6E\E0\B04Mm\9CY\C1\C5x\8A8\EE\87v\87\B6x\B7|ى~n\AD\BA/\A9\96SD\86ெ\E0+\82g[>*\A2 \82\9AX\B2b\C7\D1OG    ;\92\E6\E6x\CCS\E0\E9\8E\F3\9FE\FF\B5\BC\9FS\CC넯\A4EԨH!"N;ܨB\82\AC\F0\B5>\DC͊]\8B=\8F\CD\E4l@`\B1t2$| &\B2R\D6\D6LR\ACJ\E4Ȑ)\F2J\8B\DB\A1CO\81u\F88)\ECiٚdO{\A6\90Ó\93\B3Ad&0[\F1`\E1\8E\DBZ-\B6\FE\91\A5v4gq\9B\CEytV\F0\95\F7\BA\BCDCBɣ\A2\E0DCTd\F5\94-\A1V@QϜ\86G\BCrMlD\88\88\C0g\C18\F6\E3~\9C\B03\9Bc\A1\88}W\C5s\F60\F0f\E1\D1\B6\B9S\A3.2C\DE\85\B9(\AF\81\89\99 \85\F0Y;\8C"X'V\F2+\CC\85瘐Y\9CS\91\9B\8B}\CD҆u\97(G\B0\A7.nAf\DB>)^\F3\F9\E3hl\917\BFY["o\91\A6\8Et\96\EBdؾ[,\EA\\E7Q\C1\A3j{RB\F8i&\B7bq\CAu\AAؼ\D0\EB\9CT7b\䌄\98ќD\AA\E0\94\DB+U\A0\8D\FE\A2{բ\E4\E4PEx\8F\E5\BB\8D\F1\FA1\DET&\87KjK\90\F70E\D8\E8\E89(\A63^\93\F1\E6\B1\ED\9D\E7\E2Sds\9A\B3NF\E4YE\E4\95<^g\C5\C8y\A4/\E3o\CD\CEs\9A\90¡4$\A4R\C5\F9\BAI\EEú\9C\DC\E3OP\DCsnۺ/\B3b\A6}\DC\FD\D2'\E2]/\E0u\C0\8E\C7Oq7>\89\C64\B2Y\E89eGr\D6\ED\A5\88\8C\AA\E5N\DA\DD\E2\D9Y\A1\93FJLdx&^
\9BGMx\D2T~\E2\E4\BA\C9r\B7*n\AB\A6.\D4\D7dZ\A5\9A+\B4\E1\F1ƪ!\B2\A6sW\E7\A3͉$^9$r\B5G\C6>Q\8C1-<z>\F7\DB\B3\EEC\EEU4\97U\DF\CAL5\B5T}v\8Cd\ED\FB0\9A\D3\D4*\E2t\BAH'\CE8\9D.\9C\85\C9Z\AC#\83b/\80k\EB\B8 \EE\F4\E2\ACW[\85]|b\87\EF׉h\\8Bc\8E\B1\8B\F4\\8E >s\DC\EBq\85\E3fb\CEgk\BEq\F1\B3~\B2N\D0\F0#\B6rօc\8E\BBW\DB\F1\D5o\C3\F1-\B8҃s>n#\BC
\B5\E8u⩰\88~\8E\F3bq\C6\F5<\D5b\AE\82\A2\C3Y΂\88\95\BD\EBC\DC\81\8F\F3\EF\F5w\DA|Z\9A
\EC\G3\C7ق\B5\8B_\ED\C1\D7n\84  }\FA\84\CC\B7\9DB\86\95\B8o\C9\E2X\96\B08j\C1\D7n\A4\CD!ڐ\AF\B0\D0\A7\B6!=\\9EVq\9ES]#\A0,κl+\F3q\8B\D7֥\C5\D7o\8ErH\C8ߎ&\E4\E3JX\D8Ƈ\F8\BC\8E\EF\B4    \9Co*\B4\D1#\E4\F3  =t  
\CD\8Ek\91\EB\B3=\E7q\C1\AB\B4}q\BBq\CE[%\9F\D0HhRIl\85֙\CC;h\8EB\9B\90\CF/4\D5.\A0C\A8G?\C2r+\96?\84\AC-\B6\AE-\9C\96\DF[>\D1^\A0\DD!#\B7\EC\A5H\D5o\FB\94O\E8\AEX
n\A7\B5\82\FF\BC\96|\F6sK\81\CE\F2\D6ﴭ\EB\F0\94Óhe\AD\88E\BF\80\F2  [\87r1\B2R\C4o\87\CDyO\CE\C3\F29\A0\C7\F6Ϯg\C5\FAu\E2ȁ;\9A\DCa\E1rh[\B0U\F8S\BB\CDa(\A7
\82\AF\95\BB\FCx\AFE\C4\FB\9Cl.o\DF܅Uc\BE-\AC;=\B9\B6\B0\B0\B2p\9B\80M\8E\83˯Z;+\FF^\A7\B0v\9B\EC\B6\F3\EEت坪7_}X\B9{\C0\EE*\E5\AB^U\D4\E7V
h\E4\AA]ԁz\AE2\BB\F9;=m\F7N\F4\A2\F7y\9C\B2"\EE~O\8E\96s\E5qYu\A5"\AAN͘D\9BS\DFPt\C2;ô\B8\EF-*Cb\9C\B5+.߀
\CB\D7?<\EEݰ\D3\FF\99h6\A9
Y&\AB
\F5\9F\F6N\DB\EF\A5\E2Bü\9E\F4\DAx3\C4y_\96\D7  ׀\D5wK\8E\B3z\DE\FB8\B6\A5d|W\81렿\80sU\E8\9A\AB\87\C7iR\91\AF\9C\D7\DB\DFu:ٍ\F2wR?\88\F5\83\C6W^o]?\88N\DAb\A7\B8D\8F\AAT\\C9G
x\CA\F7:ȣ\EB\A0N\D6a\A1o[_\89M\E8+\D1\FF\EF+\F4\95\F2\86\BF;-\BAa߾\BE\9D\E4\DD\DA;\A1\AFD'\ED+\E5%:5}%z\84~\C1\A9\E9+Qr\AC}\A5\FC_\9DNf_)o\C5}\A5\A9nߩ\BBK\D6\FBs\AB\92x\A7u\97()\EE.M\DE\DD85\DD%z\ED\B2
\BE\B3\BBLT\F8\D8\C4j\E6\D4w\99\E8;\B8\CBD\C7u\99\F2\EFuOe\97\89\BEi\97\89\9D\B2.=\86.{˺LT\E8\A0\B1\AE\DCZ\DA\F6\E1\FE\A9\EB\D1Im\FEv\F5\8E\E8\84\DE{\DBzGt\CA\DEQ\BE\F4\D6\F7\8E\E81\F7\AD\ED9\99u\EAebǇGǧ\B0Ks2;>\F4\84:>߳_Ǉt|\8E\D4w8\9A\EC\FC+H\BE\D3@>\F3\B2R|@\8B>\8E\C2.\F7\A1<6\D7\D04֧%\F4\A1y^v\9F\A6\F3\B2\B6\C4p:f\B0x2\ADg\B2\9Aʢ=\C9|m\D0\FE\98CC|zo\C0\FA\F4^!J\F3\D4{\B5\8C\C2,\D6r\A4\F3\8F\F8C'~X\F0\A8?g\C8\C6Q\8ETaٌ\A2jI%\B3\89\E9\D1\F1X(\ED\D62ɸ!>O7XL\CBhH\AB?\A3\A4Ptʎb\E11\D4X\A6_\F3\B0\ACΔ\D40Kk\E8}Y\D4XU\A0\B02M2\D3=E"z2\8D\E0 C\EC\A8e\FE\C1;6\B7N\A8\A4n"S\99bz$\AE =\AAꑁ\A4\96\CA*Y\CEO4\9E@#\CD\E5\C5ң\D9!T\DD<\C1IFKgtu \A2   4j\8B\F7
d5\CE-:\E0A3G*\E7d(\9E\8D\E9Yd&\B7  q
K\95\88v\C0@x.\8E\87%5.5b\C4<4<\9Cf\83\9Ea\86\86v@\E88\B2j\8B?\8E4gѦ\B9\A2\B3\D4R\9D 4Cǚp\80\9B!:\90I!AMTuf\E8f\F4m\D4"Y\BE\C2\E5\8B\EA t6.PDO\A9q.\87\B1\94\D20\A2S\FA\F4AMH`y\91` \E7)=\8Bf0\ACUn\95t\DE\AC=fĔD\82\F6i\B6֐
\8C\A5HN=\85~\91aI=\A3M*6\CB\A7\B5\A8\82\84\BCSŻIe\A3\8F\AB\F1h\9C;\9A\92Ȣ\EB\E1\00\91*\AA*$\B7T\C7T\C9 _   %C9!U3\E2\FD)\C1F\BF\ABx\88{\A8A$?\E1\F0c\8C\A7\C4QR$ \A6$&G`\9Fq\F8\C8cC\F6R\89a/ps\CA\C5\C9h\FC;D\96\AEHn'<4\F49-#
\E9\D5`u\B98\AC㴝
Z\C7öN\A8-\D3n\C7K\9F\86\91ı\A0
\B8N\F5x\8E1ms#\86)\E94\86\97җ\D0\F8\86%;b\E6\9A7JLɲ\98b F-U\A4\EEuy\EFV\D9@J\B5γJs\96\84G\B2\AA\A1'xT\B3q#),\C1\B3Ɗ\98V"\9B\94~\E30\A5S\EE\AA\C7\E6TE\A40a!\8BZ"ʙZ\E5g+\BB:\C3,Ե2\BC\D6\F4\B3@\88u\BBz\AD\FEVV\E7\E1\BC\CE\C3\D6«\BAz\C2!\82\BE\CE\F0zֵ\92\F9:׳5\81\CEV\F3\AF\EB\FAC!\DAd\81\8E\EE\F6\80\D7\9D-\ED=\AD\81\CE6֌\E7:\BB¬=\D0#\D2p\978j\A3
\F8CY\87?ز
\A7\BE\E6@{ \BC\DECW\88\992\EB\F6Á\96\9Ev_\90u\F7\BB\BBB~\C4ъh;\9D+\83H\C5\DF\E1G!QKW\F7\FA`\A0mU؃\87¸\E8\A1ᠯ\D5\DF\E1\AE\F10Dօ"\99\00\F1"\97\88\83\F9{\F9\E1\D0*_{;k\84C\E1\A0\DF\D7\C1a\B9v\DA:\BB:\FCteWOg\AB/\E8\EAd\CD~\C5\D7\DC\EE\B7xCQZ\DA}\81k\F5u\F8ڸ8f\89\93W\E5\DA\FC\9D\FE\A0\AF\DD\C3B\DD\FE\96\00\A0AKX@\A2\EEQ\ED\82ݖ\AEΐ\FF\D2\@8\87\84\87\AE]\E5$P\00\FEk\9C  \F1;Q\\8E'\DC\E7XY\F9=\CC\84\B8EV\BB\90]nϮ\95\C2zP\9F\DCx\9D6\BF\DCF|m\A2w ?m\D8\EA\F7\B5#\C2gh,z\97sDKg\B9o\DB\C1m\A5F\91F\AD\DC\E9^k%t\E1\B6\AE\B5&\86x-ad\89[\C7\CAn\F9\9B_\C7+\F5\8A\F4\81ލ7\91\95z\D5A
3\A0\C1S\89\9E\A1:O&CqCD:^\81Iݺ\F3\98\A1$\90\9E\E2Q$\A00W*  <f\E4\D8,
(\EA\\86\E9L\8Fe\E2YL&L\C0\D5L\FC\C3\F65\9C\B1\AF)!\CBK\C0\A9䓃\C5F3\D2xK\C5\B5İa3\FC.\9C\C4SQ=\93\B4E\EA\8Bd\97:\A5B\96\F5䪞\A5z\A6\DF\CB(\D7    \97NG\FB=\8B\93SQ\ABb\C7S\D1|Ď\B3\A2\EB ;\C9G&ù3&)P\F3=\91Z\899\B5}g\D4JԲ\C3[V+Q+`O\A8V\A2'\B1V\A2\F9Z\89g\ADD\8B\EA\82㨕\E8T\B5;\FAZ\89\D4J\85\E1[T.\E1}\8EI\E2d\95K\D4.\97\D8  \95K\B4\88]\F1\BE\F1d\97L4\A5\B3.\99\E8I-\99\A8]2\B1\E3/\99\E8\F8\92\89O\C9D'-\99ر\94L4\EC\EB\EDX\DD\C5\D9\F6\AD:\AE\EA\88\E6%?\91\EA\88:\D5;\91\EA\88VG츪#:iu\C4N\A4:\E2\CEZ(\B9NY\F8\B0c(|\E8\91v\85\85Oq\ED\F0\E6Mց_!\8A\EA\C5\EF\89|g\B0A\F4\ED6\E1o\83蝩\E2\AFz^\F1\F7\D54\AE\FF\B5\F0\C8\DF0l\8Ao\8A7\C41Ym\F6\A6c\E9;cN\F5m\CD\C2of\92ɾTY\F0UJ\B0\BE\84=v%\FF3&\FE\ECs]\BDb\ECM\AD\85\BF\D6\C3k\8D\F0\97x\B5\FElL\F8\9Fz\F8c%\FCa^\A9\87\DF\EF\F0ɿ7\E1w#\F0\DF#\F0\F2(\FC\D7(\FCք\DF,\85_7\C3K&\FCg#\BC\F8\AB\90\FC\E2\FC
\82\C3/4ȇG\E1\85xބ\FF0\E1\B9F\F8\F7Z\F8\E5\FC\9F\D7\C0϶³\FB\E1\A7&\FC\C1\BC\FD\A8M>\B4~\D4\CF\FC\F0l\F9~x6\FC\C0\84\A7M\F8\BE   \DF3\E1\E0|\F7\C0,\F9\BB&\98\FF\D6O\99\F0\ED\ED\D5\F2\B7ρò5\E1 \BEi\C27Lx܄1\E1\9FM\F8\BA   \8F\99\B0߄G\AB\E1k\D7\D5\CB_3a\DF#\FB\E5}&<\F2\F0\E5\F2#\FBᑫ\DD\B5^~\F8\F2c\F0\F0
\F7W\EB\E1!\FEi4\E1+&\EC5\E1M\F8\B2
_\AA\84/>P/Q\85\F6\D4\C8\D4Þ\F82\FD\85Q\F8\BC   \BBM\D8e\C2\E7j\E0~>{_\A5\FC\D9F\B8\AF\FEA\85{\E4\DE\F8\8C  \F7|\BA\\BEǄO\97\C3\DDw\9D%߭\C2]wV\C9w\9DwV\C1n7\E1S#\F2\A7L\A9\80O\E2\A1O\8E\C0m\B7Vʷͅ[+\E1\A3\F0\F1[\F6\CB7ᖝ\97˷\EC\87[\AEv\EF\FCX\BD\BC\F3rع\C2\FD\B1z\B8ل\9Bn\F4\CA7\99p\A3v\A0\98;|p\C3G\CB\E4j\E1\A3ep=.\\AF\C2u\A8\A9\EB\EAa{5\k¶\8FT\CB\DBL\F8H5\c\C2\D5&\e\B1+\B7n\95\AF4a\EBV\F8{\B6\84\A7\CB[\EA\E1\C3&\9B\B0\B9\86\CAa\90   \D9Q0F!3
W\8CB\DA݄\94    \89ٰɄ\8D\D5\CD\F2\C6\C4M\88m\85~\9CDM\D0LPM\88\98\D0g\82\B26\8C\CA\E1r.3\E1&\AC_G\E5\F5\A3\B0\8E\C2\DAg\C9k\A1ׄ\A4\DC\D3\E1\E9\92\AA\E4Й\AC\85KW\9F!_jBwt\99\D0\D9Q%w\9A\D0Q\ED&\AC\C1\9D5&\ACTɫπ\C0\CC
9P\AB*\A0̈́\95#\E0\81VZ\\F3\E5\96Qh\DE\BE5\B0\F7\9Bp\C9\C55\F2%\B5p\F1\F2\D3\E5\8Bk`\F9\B2
y\F9\8A\B1\D3aY,5\E1"޷\A4V~\DF(,Y\%/\A9\85ŋ\CA\E4\C5U\B0\A8΂\A6
h|o\99\DCh\C2{\CB`AC\99\BC\A0\CA\C0;\FF4\D9[\F3OO#\xA\BD|\A1
̫\91/\A8\87y50\F7\FCzy\AEί\87\F3\EA\CB\E4\F3N\87\FA28ׄ9&ԝ\B3Q\CE\D95\C0Tx\CF(\CCBf\A90\B3\CEA
\9Ec\C2٣\F0\EEf8'g\99p\A6
\EFBM\BD˄xh\C6Y0݄Z\CE0\A1jL\A8FY\AB\9B\A1j+\9C\AEB\A5   \E53\E4
\CA\BA|\94\99@\AB\E04\A6!\D84Jk\A1D7n\BA\D1\A6\AE\82    .\9C\BB\E6\83T\C4i\9F\A4n\BFY\BA\F0oᇼ\DD\F1g\E6\FF?ͦ\8A
endstream
endobj
12 0 obj
<</Type /Font
/BaseFont /Helvetica
/Subtype /Type1
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
/Font <<
/F1 5 0 R
/F2 12 0 R
>>
/XObject <<
>>
>>
endobj
13 0 obj
<<
/Producer (tFPDF 1.25)
/CreationDate (D:20200105140137)
>>
endobj
14 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 1 0 R
>>
endobj
xref
0 15
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000275 00000 n 
0000008474 00000 n 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000087 00000 n 
0000000362 00000 n 
0000000512 00000 n 
0000001049 00000 n 
0000001443 00000 n 
0000001511 00000 n 
0000001742 00000 n 
0000001983 00000 n 
0000008377 00000 n 
0000008589 00000 n 
0000008667 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 15
/Root 14 0 R
/Info 13 0 R
>>
startxref
8717
%%EOF
```

Comment: An obvious way to obtain an invalid PDF file is to get a PHP error message randomly printed inside the code.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, how to verify such a case? I've update the question with the binary data generated.

Comment: Oh well... It doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: What does "_the document is unreadable_" mean exactly? Any chance to save this "unreadable" document and make it accessible to us?

Comment: @JanSlabon: it's the message the browser's plugin says (translated from Italian). If you read the question, the document is already there.

Comment: You cannot share a binary file via copy&paste. Also the file you pasted is the result of the call of the output method with the destination set to "F". This is not the same as saving the result which should have gone through your application workflow. But does the pasted result already have an issue? I mean can it be opened or not? Please share a download link if it is already "unreadable". Otherwise dump the content of your response object or save the data which is received by the browser.